# Como modelar tabelas para armazenar tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server, modelagem

Tenho uma base de dados SQL Server onde tenho uma tabela de vídeos ligados a várias tag´s.

Como é feito aqui no fórum onde cada post esta ligado a várias tags.

Qual a melhor prática para modelar o banco de dados?

A principio pensei em algo assim, mas não sei se é a melhor abordagem!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Um video está para varias tags, assim com uma tag está ligada em vários videos, muitos para muitos (N:M) ... acredito ser a melhor maneira pelas informações da pergunta

Comment: Jota não precisa daquele id da VideoTag, pode colocar idVideo e idTag como chave primaria

Comment: @Virgilio Novic Normalmente não crio chave composta para facilitar o acesso usando Linq. O sistema que ira manter a base é Asp.Net MVC 4.6.

Comment: se for Entity Framework 6 você não precisa criar ... se for Entity Framework Core até o momento precisa ser desse jeito ... então depende mesmo de você, ao meu entender já está correto o seu diagrama ...

Comment: Depende... Um vídeo terá uma única tag ou poderá ter mais de uma tag? // Se a relação for N:M, sugiro que retire a coluna `id` de `VideoTag` e que coloque o par (`idTag`, `idVideo`), nessa ordem, como chave primária. Senão a pesquisa por tag na tabela `VideoTag` vai ficar _uma carroça_.